# Redirect one url to another url using .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My website was recently hacked, and many posts in Japanese were indexed. Now I want to redirect all posts with japanese language to their main url.

Index Japanese Post

`www.acbd.com/123/?japanese`

Want to redirect to

`www.abcd.com/123/`

```
Redirect 301 /en/php/project.html http://www.example.org/newpage.html
```

I have tried above code but its not working. Please help.

Comment: Use a `RewriteCond` to check query string and `RewriteRule` to remove

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^japanese$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,END]
```

Best is to implement such rules in the http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (often called ".htaccess"), but you need to enable that feature first (see the documentation of the `AllowOverride` directive for that).

---

If the query string is *not* a literal (as you describe it in the question), but changes, then certainly variants of above condition can be implemented to take that into account. Here are some examples:

A condition accepting a fixed set of known query strings that should get matched:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(japanese|chinese|russian)$
```

A combined condition matching simple "words", but not key value pairs as typically used for application logic:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\w+=.*
```

A condition matching *all* arbitrary query strings, but note that this means that you cannot use regular query strings in your application any more:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
```

Comment: What should be the code if "Japanese" changes to any keyword?

Comment: @ChhayaParikh What do you mean by "any keyword"? Completely arbitrary, so _any_ query string, or a certain pattern of a query string or a fixed set of possible query strings?

Comment: I added some possible condition patterns, but it is not really possible to clearly answer to your question without you specifying the situation in a more precise way. Sorry.